# An instance of this app is already exists at the specified location - when installing apps using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am installing apps using powershell script and I want my script as rerunnable.

```
try
{
    $web.GetAppInstanceById()
    $appIoStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($AppFilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $appInstance = $web.LoadAndInstallApp($appIoStream) | Out-Null
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host $appInstance.Id
}
catch
{
    $appIoStream.Dispose();
    Write-Host "Unable to Install App -" $AppName ": $_.Exception.Message" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
    return
}
```

Using this I can able to achieve the apps to be installed in the site collection.But when I am again running the powershell script I got an error that **"an instance of this app is already exists at specified location"**. How can I handle this?

Comment: Can please update your question with requirements around what your **really** need to achive?

Comment: Sure...I will update

Comment: Hi @kai..Updated the question

Comment: Thanks for an update! Other users will have a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: Nice @Kumaraguru, after deleting my app in my dev site, I had to remove it from the recycle bin. Works like a charm now! You da man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose I would recommend [PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) module.

This module already contains a lot of helpful commands for managing SharePoint, including apps.

For example take a look at the [apps](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Documentation#apps) cmdlets:

- Uninstall‑PnPAppInstance
- Get-PnPAppInstance
- Import-PnPAppPackage

With help of PnP you can solve your issue in a following way:

```
$app = Get-PnPAppInstance | ? {$_.Title -eq "<your app title here>"}
if($app -ne $null){
  Uninstall‑PnPAppInstance -Identity $app
}    
Import-PnPAppPackage -Path c:\files\my_app_file.app
```

Only 5 lines of code.

**UPD**
Before running the script you need to connect to SharePoint using `Connect-PnPOnline` cmdlet. It asks for credentials, if you want to store credentials in your script (not or good approach and bad practice, but ok for development), you can instantiate a new site with PnP-Powershell using below code:

```
$username = "user@organization.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "pass"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credentials $cred
```

Comment: Thank You Man...It is working when deploying one app....But I have another problem when deploying second app..Error:(a different version of this app is already installed with the same version number).Can you help me!

Comment: For your second app, did you change `ProductId` param?

Comment: No..But i am already deployed the app with different version using Visual Studio in same site collection.Is that cause problem? If so, how can I delete that?

Comment: Yes, that might be an issue. You can delete it using UI, from Site Content, then from recycle bin.

Comment: I am deleted in both site contents and recycle bin...But still causing problem

Comment: Did you change `ProductId`? And did you delete from second stage recycle bin?

Comment: No i didn't changed product ID and deleted in both stage

Comment: Every new app needs unique ProductId, for your other app, try to use different id.

Comment: By changing the version of apps I am able to achieve what I want without an error.Is that negligible or it is good to change the product Id

Comment: ProductId should be unique for the app. I mean you are not able to have two apps with the same ProductId.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options:

1. Change the ProductId in your appmanifest.xml in your VS project.
2. You need to remove the app from apps catalog or from site content and then upload it again.
3. Remove the app reference from recycle bin of SharePoint site.

After that you can run your powershell command and verify.